# How can i handle "connect ETIMEDOUT" error when the URL is overloaded "Bottlenecks"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, http-post, etimedout

I am posting request with NodeJs. Here is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');


async function sendRequest(obj){
 try{  // TRY STARTS HERE
var requestTarget = await rp({
          method: 'POST',
          uri: obj.url,
          headers: {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ar-AE;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "cookie":obj.cookie,
    "Referer":obj.referer ,
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  },
          timeout:16000,
        body : obj.body
        }).then(
          (response)=>{
return response
          })
           // TRY ENDS HERE
}catch(error){ // catch STARTS HERE
  console.error( " error is :" +error);
}// catch ENDS HERE
console.log(" response is : "  +requestTarget);


}
```

Anyway, I've got Problem with request: connect ETIMEDOUT when I run the code and I have no idea how to fix it.

What could cause this error ? and how can i handle this server?

Answer (score 2):

`ETIMEDOUT` means that the server didn't answer to your request in the given timeout(in your example 16 seconds) time. That error can be handled in the catch block.

Comment: i tried with 180000*2 and the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your question title mentioned that you believe your target server is overloaded.  ETIMEDOUT errors can come up in that situation. Denial of service attack?

You don't have much you can do in your code attempting the outbound connect, except catch the error, wait for a period of time and try again.

Ideally, each consecutive time you catch the error you will wait for twice as much time before trying again. For the first wait, use one second. Then wait 2, 4, 8, 16, and so forth.  You want to give the target server a chance to work through its connection queue, and hammering on it slows that process.

After a minute or so you should give up. Deliver an error to your error logging system if you have one. If your service is a web service, to YOUR client deliver a 500 (generic server error), 502 (bad gateway to upstream server), or 504 (upstream server timed out), depending on what makes sense for your appication.

If you also control the target server, you can figure out what is happening there. You may need more capacity. Or a rogue client may be hitting the target really hard. It's possible your target is experiencing a denial-of-service attack.

Handling ETIMEDOUT errors is a pain in the xxx. If your service isn't mission-critical and this doesn't happen very often you can simply issue the 500, 502, or 504 error to your client. Don't forget to log the error, though: fixing the situation may require human intervention.

Comment: While I wait for twice as much time before trying again, there are other people out there requesting the available limit of the appointments, after a while when the server recover  , i have nothing else to request for, they are taking all the available appointments and i take only this error
note : *** .... its the server ip

Comment: Ah. You don't control the overloaded service. You're probably competing with various bots to use the service. Can you work with them to resolve the overload? If not, I suppose you can go ahead and retry with a shorter delay. And, you can probably shorten the timeout in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because the port was blocked, the error happened.
Please check that the port was enable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).